# Splash screen via self.present from main view controller doesn't appear properly (using Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, splash-screen

Total novice here and started to explore Xcode environment whilst following a study book. I got distracted by how to have a splash screen appear when you open an app. The built-in launch screen method doesn't stay on the screen very long, so I used Chat GPT to find out how to have it stay there longer. What it's told me works insofar as a second view appears, but it's like it is transparent and you can just see the main view underneath.

I have following code in the ViewController that is there by default:

```
import UIKit

class MainScreenController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view
        
        }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            
            let fakeLoadingView = FakeSplashScreen()
            self.present(fakeLoadingView, animated: true)
        }
    
    
}

class FakeSplashScreen: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print("This did load")
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) { // Simulate a 2-second delay
            self.dismiss(animated: true) // Dismiss the fake loading view
            //Continue to your app's main interface
            
        print("I was dismissed")
            
        }
        
   }
    
}
```

Then have this in the "Main" storyboard, with just a single label:

[image]

Then this as the splash screen:

[image]

When it runs, it seems to work - the "This did load" and "I was dismissed" print so it's running, but the splash screen looks like this before it disappears:

[image]

Custom class of the splash screen viewcontroller is set to FakeSplashScreen, besides that haven't changed anything.

Please could someone explain what is happening and what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that when you **present** a view controller, UIKit:

- covers the screen with a "dimming" view
- slides up the new controller
- and scales down the current view

With the code you posted, your `FakeSplashScreen` has NO content ... and even the root view has no background color.

So, if this is your "main" controller:

[image]

presenting your `FakeSplashScreen` looks like this:

[image]

all we see is the dimming view and the slightly scaled-down main view.

If you add only this to `viewDidLoad()` in `FakeSplashScreen`:

```
view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
```

it will look like this:

[image]

and after 2 seconds that yellow view will "slide down"

There are many ways to implement a "splash screen" -- depending on what all you want to do would determine the best approach.

ONE approach, though, is to:

- in **main** controller's `viewDidLoad()`

  - load `FakeSplashScreen` as a **child** view controller
  - add its view as a subview
  - constrain it to cover the entire view
- then, still in **main** controller, in `viewDidAppear()`

  - start the two-second delay
  - "fade out" the splash view
  - remove it
  - remove the child controller

Quick example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var splashVC: FakeSplashScreen!
    var splashView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // whatever we're doing in Main Controller loading / preparing
        // ...
        
        // load FakeSplashScreen as a child controller
        self.splashVC = FakeSplashScreen()
        self.addChild(splashVC)
        // safely unwrap optional
        guard let v = splashVC.view else {
            fatalError("Check your code!")
        }
        // configure and add FakeSplashScreen's view to self.view
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(v)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        splashVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        self.splashView = v
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) { // Simulate a 2-second delay
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.splashView.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: { _ in
                self.splashView.removeFromSuperview()
                self.splashVC.willMove(toParent: nil)
                self.splashVC.removeFromParent()
            })
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

---

```
class FakeSplashScreen: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        // setup / configure the "splash" screen
    }
    
}
```

---

Looks kinda like this:

[image] [image] [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: Thank you. This looks like it answers my question - currently away from my Mac so will work through properly when I’m back. Thank you again 